# ReactJS / Spring Boot email confirmation request parameter

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a login and signup form working, after signup the user is sent an email to confirm their account before they can log in.

I am using Spring Boot and the email link takes the user to my /confirm REST endpoint that will generate a unique token and confirm the user account (Enabling them) and allow them to login.

If i try to set the link to my front end like this http://localhost:3000/confirm/"+ confirmationToken , it redirects me but does not actually confirm the account.

The issue I'm struggling to understand is how I can prevent  the email link from taking the user to the spring boot endpoint and send them to the React route AND confirm the account by calling the /confirm endpoint I have.

At the moment this is what I have.

---

**EmailService.java**

- Responsible to send the email with the link that takes the user to my react route (But this doesn't actually enable their account), which is what I can't figure out.

```java
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailService.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendMail(String email, String confirmationToken){
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo(email);
        mailMessage.setSubject("Account Activation!");
        mailMessage.setText("To confirm your account, please click here : "
                +"http://localhost:3000/confirm/"+ confirmationToken
                + "   Note: This link will expire after 10 minutes.");
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

---

**AuthController.java**

- /register endpoint to create a user, but their account is disabled
- /confirm Checks if link is still valid (10 minutes) and confirms the user account.

```java
 @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {
        // validation
        userValidator.validate(user, result);
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = errorValidationService.validationService(result);
        if(errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        // the email confirmation token
        userService.saveUser(user);

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = userService.createToken(user);
        emailService.sendMail(user.getEmail(), confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken());

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/test/user").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(new ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully! Please check your email for a verification link < " + user.getEmail() + " >"));
    }



    @GetMapping("confirm")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMethodName(@RequestParam("token") String token) {

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = userService.findByConfirmationToken(token);

        if (confirmationToken == null) throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid token");

        User user = confirmationToken.getUser();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if((confirmationToken.getExpiredAt().getTime() - calendar.getTime().getTime()) <= 0) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Link expired. Generate new link from http://localhost:3000/signin");
        }

        user.setEmailVerified(true);

        userService.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Account verified successfully!");
    }
```

---

On my front end I have these routes

**App.js**

```js
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/signin" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />

        <Route path="/confirm/:token" element={<EmailConfirmedComponent />} />
        
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

---

**EmailConfirmedComponent.js**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const EmailConfirmedComponent = () => {

    return (
        <div style={{margin: "2rem"}}>
            <h1>Thank you for creating an account!</h1>

            <Link to="/signin">
             <button className="btn btn-primary">Go to login</button>
            </Link>

        </div>
    )
}

export default EmailConfirmedComponent;
```

Comment: It isn't a parameter but a path variable you are currently using.

Comment: In the emailService? I changed it to "http://localhost:3000/confirm?token="+ confirmationToken, 3000 is where the React client is running on. But i'm still confused on how to actually get this done

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not mixing service URIs with client URL, it's not something you'd run into once you deploy both projects anyway.

Solution:

The email can continue showing URL as `'http://<hostname>/confirm/' + confirmationToken`.

Change `EmailConfirmedComponent` so it makes a REST call to your service with a specific URI for creating an account.

Your service URIs should start with a custom service context path to avoid conflict with UI routes. e.g. `localhost:3000/my-service/confirm`.

To do so, add the following to your service `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/my-service
```